# NSURLConnection getting limited to a Single Connection at a time?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, comet

OK - let's rephrase this whole question shall we?

Is there any way to tell if iOS is holding onto an NSURLConnection after it has finished & returned it's data?

I've got 2 NSURLConnections I'm instantiating & calling into a server with. The first one initiates the connection with the server and then goes into a COMET style long-polling wait while another user interacts with the request.  The second one goes into the server and triggers a cancel mechanism which safely ends the first request and causes both to return successfully with a "Cancelled by you" message.

In the happy path case the Cancel button will never be clicked. But it's possible to click it and exit the current action.

This whole scenario works GREAT once. And then never works again (until the app is reset).

It's as though the first time thru one of the connections is never released and we are from then on limited to only a single connection because one of them is locked.

---

BTW I've tried NSURLConnection, AFNetwork, MKNetworkKit, ASIHTTPRequest - no luck what-so-ever with any other frameworks. NSURLConnection should do what I want. It's just ... not letting go of one of my connections.

Comment: After much testing it seems like using long polling on iOS simply isn't possible at this time. I wish it were as it would simplify my code and allow me to keep one API for iOS and Android. But for now I've had to implement an ugly simple polling API for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So unfortunately with the lack of a real solution to this issue being found in all my testing I've had to implement simple polling to resolve the issue.

I've also had to implement iOS only APIs on the server.

What this comes down to is an API to send up a command and put it into a queue on the server, then using an NSTimer on the client to check the status of the of the queued item on a regular interval.

Until I can find out how to make multiple connections on iOS with long-polling this is the only working solution.  Once I have a decent amount of points I'll gladly bounty them away for a solution to this :(

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the cancellation request in Step 2 is leaving the HTTP connection open.

I don't know exactly how the NS* classes work with respect to the [HTTP/1.1 recommendation of at most two simultaneous connections](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2006/Mar/msg01058.html), but let's assume they're enforcing at most two connections. Let's suppose the triggering code in Instance A (steps 1 and 3 of your example) cleans up after itself, but the cancellation code in Instance B (steps 2 and 4) leaves the connection open. That might explain what you are observing.

If I were you, I'd compare the code that runs in step 1 against the code that runs in step 2. I bet there's a difference between them in terms of the way they clean up after themselves.

Comment: I've added logging to nearly every line of code. The only deltas are the API URL is slightly different for each method. And the data being posted is slightly different. I did consider that potentially it was a cache issue because the cancellation code was always sending the same data but the trigger code had some uniqueness to it due to a date/time stamp. I've eliminated that by adding a date/time stamp to both calls. Thanks though. :(

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong,
iOS/Mac holds on to a NSURLConnection as long as the "Keep-Alive" header dictates it to.

But as a iOS developer you shouldn't be worried. any reason why you would like to know that?

Comment: I'm experiencing an issue where I'm trying to operate with 2 NSURLConnections at the same time. And it works initially but never on any following iteration. It's as though iOS is never cleaning up one of the initial connections. But I can't find any documentation as to why I'm experiencing this. I suspect I'm doing something wrong but it's simply not clear as to what.  I'll check the headers. Thank you.

Comment: I can't find what alternate value I would set that header to be to disable this functionality. It seems as though its set to Keep-Alive by default.

Comment: If your server is Apache, you can change that by editing the httpd.conf file in your server. If using nginx edit the appropriate file (I guess it's nginx.conf). These files should be in /var/etc/httpd/httpd.conf or /var/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: I believe I need the setting ON globally, is there any way to turn it off for a specific request?

Comment: I don't think you can turn off "Keep-Alive" from client side.